# Use badgeview for tablayout design support

Tags: android, badge, androiddesignsupport

Hi any ideas how to use [viewbadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) with support design Tablayout.
I'm not able to get the title textview reference from tablayout.

I tried using `tabLayout.getChildAt(0);` but it sets the badgeview at of SlidingTabStrip.
Also I took a look at Tablayout.Tab class, seems there is no option for getting the textview or parent view.